# すべての列を参照して正規化、標準化をする方法

Tags: python, python3, jupyter-notebook

12行*30列のcsvファイルに保存されたデータ（da_all）があるのですがこれを以下のようなプログラムで正規化を実行しようとしたところ（問題がありそうな箇所を抜粋）行ごとで正規化が行われてしまっていました。すべてのデータを参照し最大値1、最小値０にしてほしく困っています。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pickle
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler([0,1])
scaler.fit(da_all)
data_del_mms = scaler.transform(da_all)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing

data = np.random.randint(0,10,size=(3,10))
print(data)
#array([[3, 1, 6, 0, 4, 2, 9, 5, 2, 8],
#       [2, 8, 0, 6, 5, 0, 2, 9, 2, 6],
#       [4, 7, 2, 5, 9, 5, 4, 4, 8, 6]])

data = np.ravel(data)[None,:].T
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(data)
data = scaler.transform(data)
data = data.T.reshape(3,10)
print(data)
#array([[0.33333333, 0.11111111, 0.66666667, 0.        , 0.44444444,
#        0.22222222, 1.        , 0.55555556, 0.22222222, 0.88888889],
#       [0.22222222, 0.88888889, 0.        , 0.66666667, 0.55555556,
#        0.        , 0.22222222, 1.        , 0.22222222, 0.66666667],
#       [0.44444444, 0.77777778, 0.22222222, 0.55555556, 1.        ,
#        0.55555556, 0.44444444, 0.44444444, 0.88888889, 0.66666667]])
```